# Replace all content between characters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm attempting to make a simple markdown converter to get better at JS and Regex.

I now need to find everything between two asterisks, and wrap them in `<i>` tags:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U95FP/1/)

```
var html = '*abc is a string*';

var html = html.replace(/\*/g , '<i>');

console.log(html);
```

RESULT:

`<i>abc is a string<i>`

I have also seen an answer to a related question, but I'm unsure how to adjust my code accordingly, or what it actually does:

`(?s)<h1>.+</h1>`

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see what problem you're having.

Comment: Edited. Replace them with `<i>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to get the content that should be wrapped in the HTML tags:

```
var html = html.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g , '<i>$1</i>');
```

Explanation of `([^*]+)`:

```
(        # start of capture group
  [^     # start of negated character class (match any character not listed)
    *    # literal asterisk character
  ]      # end of negated character class
  +      # match at least one of the previous token
)        # end of capture group
```

So `[^*]+` means "match at least one character that is not `*`". This has the effect that all characters up to the next `*` are matched.

Comment: Thanks. I keep seeing `([^*]+)` — could you elaborate on what that part does?

Comment: You could also use `.+?` instead to match all content up to the very next `*` making this inner part more flexible.

Comment: @cepharum: Sure, but I like to avoid lazy quantifiers. Why would it be more flexible?

Comment: @Felix Kling: ... for `.+?` doesn't care for bounding characters itself, but relies on defining boundaries before and after it. It's not tightly related to those definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp `[^*]+`.

```
'*abc is a string*'.match(/[^*]+/gi);  //["abc is a string"]
```

Comment: You don't need to escape * in a character class

Answer (score 0):

You can match part of the string and then use that in the replace call as documented in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Example.3A_Using_a_regular_expression_to_change_data_format

Example:

```
'*abc is a string*'.replace(/\*([\w\s]+)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>')
> '<i>abc is a string</i>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use adjusted greediness in your regexp (`+?` in my pattern below), though it is less performant (see http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance). Next try using callback:

```
var result = source.replace( /(*|_)(.+?)(\1)/g, function( all, starter, content, ender ) {
    return "<i>" + content + "</i>";
} );
```

Using callback might improve your code's flexibility:

```
var result = source.replace( /(*|_)(.+?)(\1)/g, function( all, starter, content, ender ) {
    switch ( starter ) {
        case '*' :
            return "<strong>" + content + "</strong>";
        case '_' :
            return "<em>" + content + "</em>";
    }
} );
```