# how to replace specific text wrapping characters with span tags?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown-it

**Desired Behaviour**

Replace `::text::` with `<span>text</span>`.

For example, given a string like:

```
Here is a ::test span:: and another ::span::, colons in this context eg: 
http://somelink.com are not effected.
```

How can the `::` characters be replaced with open and closing `<span>` tags like this:

```
Here is a <span>test span</span> and another <span>span</span>, colons 
in this context eg: http://somelink.com are not effected.
```

**What I've Tried**

I'm actually trying to replicate the behaviour of:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-span

a plugin for the very helpful [markdown-it parser](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) as it seems to have a bug (that I can't figure out how to fix), which has been [discussed in an issue here](https://github.com/pnewell/markdown-it-span/issues/1):

> There is a bug in code that cause creating span tag twice.
>
> ```
> ::spanned:: => <span><span>spanned</span></span>
> ```
>
> Also, input like `http:` is converted into `http::`.

**Edit:**

I have just come across similar question here, which might have the answer...

[Replace all content between characters with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23199459)

Answer (score 2):

This seems simple enough with the regex `/::([^::]+)::/g`:

```js
var s = 'Here is a ::test span:: and another ::span::, colons in this context eg: http://somelink.com are not effected.';

console.log(s.replace(/::([^::]+)::/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
```

Comment: But i think this character `:` should be escaped, am i wrong?

Comment: `:` doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple enough. This one worked for me: `(::)([\w\s]+)(::)` replace it with `<span>$2</span>`.

```
::text::    => <span>text</span>
::spanned:: => <span>spanned</span>


Here is a ::test span:: and another ::span::, colons in this context eg: 
http://somelink.com are not effected.  
=> 
Here is a <span>test span</span> and another <span>span</span>, colons in this 
context eg: 
http://somelink.com are not effected.
```